# Interpretation of a difference-in-difference model

Tags: r, regression, mathematical-statistics, difference-in-difference, lm

I am running a basic difference-in difference (DiD) model. I would like to explain the effect of increasing the price of fares for students only. I use DiD with adults as a control group. I have monthly data of tickets sold for each category.

To avoid seasonality I have data before treatment, that is from April 2021 - December 2021 and after treatment. It started the 1st of April, so the post-periods are from April 2022 - December 2022. Can I do DiD like this?

When I did a calculation by hand (not modelled), I realized that the ratio of students/adults was 0,518 before treatment and 0,35 after the treatment. I calculated that the decrease that the treatment meant for students was around 31%. I calculated that with an assumption that the ratio before would stay the same because with DiD I presumed that the only thing that changed is the TREATMENT.

Also, I calculated how much demand for adults went up, it was around 81%, while the students went up only 21,4 %. So, I used the same logic, what is the difference between the counterfactual when the students would rise 81% too and the real state of world.

Then, I ran a DiD model using the standard `lm()` model using no other predictors, all the averages of the groups stayed the same as expected. But, when I calculated the counterfactual to know how many students would be there if there was no intervention, it gives me a way higher number.

In the DiD analysis, the demand went lower by 50% and not 31%.

How is this possible? The DiD counterfactual somehow presumes that the students should increase the demand even more! Why?

This is how the data look:
[image]

And here my dif in dif results:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Ratio of students to adults:[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please explain why, or how, you avoided seasonality? Do you have 8 months of data before *and* after treatment?

Comment: @ThomasBilach Yes exactly, the treatment happened at 1st of April 2022. So I used the same months before and after the treatment. Before: April 21 - Dec 21 and after April 22 - Dec 22.

Comment: I have 9 month before and after the treatment actually.

Comment: So you’re excluding the months from January to March in both years?

Comment: Yes, because the treatment happened in April, the first months of the year would fall into the pre-treatment period and the seasonality would be a problem.

Comment: By doing this I can basically compare the comparable. But when doing it "manually" I get different results, maybe my intuition is wrong.. That is my question. Whether adults increase by around 81 % and I can assume that students should increase the same % because the only difference is the treatment, then I get contrafactual. But in dif in dif, I get different results.

Comment: It is generally bad practice to exclude pre-treatment periods. You’re imposing arbitrary breaks in your time series data. We need to settle that before going into your question. Is there some seasonality that manifests in one group more than the other?

Comment: @ThomasBilach Well yes, there is some, I put the grapf below, but we can see that for example those excluded months that are pre-treatment in both categories, would fall then to pre-treatment period.

Comment: @ThomasBilach I just realised where is my problem. Its the big difference between the coontrol and treatment group in absolute terms. When i do dif in dif in Log-level specification I get the expected results. However, I dont get, how this is not a problem in a stanard level - level specification? Isnt it always a problem if the levels of treatment and controls are different, then we are not comparing comparable no?